# Yajsw Stop INFO Log message while start stop daemon under linux

Tags: java, linux, daemon, java-service-wrapper

I am using Yajsw to run my app as Daemon process.

for status call,I would like to see "Running" or "stopped" but i got messages shown below

```
SW043305-SRV01:/etc/init.d # ./testDaemon status 
15.06.2012 16:13:57 org.apache.commons.vfs.VfsLog info 
INFO: Using "/tmp/vfs_cache" as temporary files store. 
15.06.2012 16:13:58 org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixService init 
INFO: /etc/init.d/testDaemon already exists 
15.06.2012 16:13:58 org.rzo.yajsw.os.posix.PosixService getPid 
INFO: wrapper pid file: /var/run/wrapper.testDaemon.pid
```

How can i customize the printed result.messages good under windows,is any thing specially to be done for linux.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the Tanuki Software equivalent to this product for 4+ years, and from the get go my approach included the fact that (in your case) YAJSW doesn't really know what the status of the underlying app is - all it knows is that it started up a JVM instructing it to load up the class you specified in its config file, and the JVM hasn't responded negatively to YAJSW or terminated yet.

So - I wanted to leave my java app blind but make it possible for everyone to know where the 24x7 app was in its work, so my java daemon typically posted status- and action-oriented information to a database table - I built a simple swing client to display historical and current status data. Mine was a simple point solution that didn't merit a whole lot of operationally-focused work, but I did as well add support that would make the demon as autonomous as possible (not require operational intervention).

I added, for example, logic to identify and recover from Oracle database errors, including identifying retryable requests where errors were temporary in nature (out-of-space, Oracle DB instance hasn't started up completely yet, Oracle DB instance is shutting down, etc.) that I could echo status info to status table, and then retry regularly until successful.